# How to stop bones from distorting parts of mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

Sorry if this a stupid, often asked question, but I've consulted numerous tutorials and guides and forum posts and such and such on this particular problem and they've at best only partly worked, so I guess it's either something more specific to what I'm trying to do or something's going over my head.

I have this model I've downloaded, and I've rigged it with a pre-made armature so I can mod it into a PC game, as such:

[image: Regular Isabelle model]

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zRnde6Y5ds) thoroughly multiple times, along with some extra help from the creator of the video on the side, and I've gotten the rig to work, but my issue is that the model distorts when I move the bones; for example, when I try to move the arm:

[image: Punished Isabelle with distorted face]

I've tried weight painting but that, at best, has only worked a little. Today I've been messing around with unassigning and removing vertex groups, but that has either done nothing or caused parts of the model to disappear. Anyone know how I could keep its face from being distorted when I move its limbs? Again, sorry if I made any amateur mistakes, I'm a newbie to this stuff :P

Here's my blender file if anyone wants to take a look: https://ufile.io/01ii4

Comment: I honestly bad at blender and I’ve put animation on pause for 6 months but I really wanted to say, I hope it worked out all right and I’m happy for you, if you finish may I have a copy of the rig

Comment: Your file has been automatically deleted. Upload it again.